# Adding a second legend to Plot?

Tags: plotting, graphics

I have the following plot:

```
Plot1=Plot[Exp[-0.03*t,{t,0,1000}];

Show[Plot1,LineLegend[{Black,Gray,Cyan},{"test1","test2","test3"}]]
```

Is there a way to add a second legend that only contains markers (say, circles and triangles)?

Comment: If you uploaded a drawing of what you were seeking, it would be easier to help you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Legended[
 Plot[
  Evaluate@Table[Exp[-(0.03)^n*t], {n, 1, 3}],
  {t, 0, 1000},
  PlotLegends -> Automatic],
 Placed[PointLegend[
   ColorData[97] /@ Range[3], {"Marker1", "Marker2", "Marker3"},
   LegendLayout -> "Row",
   LegendMarkers -> (Style[#, 14] & /@ {"\[EmptyCircle]", 
       "\[EmptyUpTriangle]", "\[EmptySquare]"})], Below]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

You can use a list of multiple legends as the option setting for `PlotLegends`:

```
Plot[Evaluate @ Table[Exp[-(0.03)^n*t], {n, 1, 3}], {t, 0, 1000}, 
 PlotLegends -> 
  {Placed[{"test 1", "test 2", "test 3"}, Right], 
   Placed[PointLegend[{"Marker 1", "Marker 2", "Marker 3"}, 
     LegendMarkers -> Thread[Style[{"○", "△", "□"}, 14]]], Below]}]
```

[image]